# Java enum - How to call another enum value in enum's constructor

Tags: java, enums, static

My question is how to code so I don't get *Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Rarity* as error msg while refering to another enum value which is supposed as I know to be static, ie. why do I have to refer main (the package of 'Rarity.java') for each Rarity.[...]?

Here is the code :

```
public enum Card {

SPARKLEGAZE("Sparklegaze", main.Rarity.COMMON), // WORKING
ABBEND("Abbend", Rarity.COMMON),                // NOT WORKING
...
```

The Rarity source :

```
package main;

public enum Rarity {

    COMMON(50),
    EPIC(6.25),
    DIVINE(1.5625);

    // Some useless code for this post

    private double Weight;

    Rarity(double weight) {

        Weight = weight;

    }

    // Some useless code for this post

}
```

(for those wondering Rarity.java is not useless since its only & private field 'Weight' is used in random selection in "useless method for this post").

Thanks for taking time to read and maybe mind this ;).

Comment: " why do I have to refer main" You say above it doesn't work if you specify `main`.

Comment: By not working I meant the error message in italic

Comment: @AndyTurner 'can't figure out where...

Comment: Do you have a field called `Rarity` inside your `Card` enum?  If so, that's probably not the best plan.

Comment: You should consider making `Card` a class instead of an enum. Just a suggestion

Comment: @(Not in the comments anymore) I answered but didn't saved apparently, I said that yeah I've been blind because one of the `Card` fileds was named `Rarity` thank you all

Comment: @Wamadahama Yes that's something I thought, but for now `Card` has no method behaviour, but even if time brings me the idea of any behaviour, I'll keep it as an enum and just override methods in the enum consts declaration.